# Rails 4 creating relational record

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

I am having some issues creating a record from a relational record.  This code creates a new user perfectly however it seems that it skips over creating the user's profile all together. It also throws no errors.

any help would be great.

#### Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
    if user = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email)  
     user
    else
      user = User.create( provider:   auth.provider, 
                          uid:        auth.uid,
                          email:      auth.info.email,
                          password:   Devise.friendly_token[0,20] )
      
      user.build_profile( username:    auth.extra.raw_info.username, 
                           first_name:  auth.info.first_name,
                           last_name:   auth.info.last_name,
                           gender:      auth.extra.raw_info.gender,  
                           country:     auth.extra.raw_info.locale,
                           image:       auth.info.image )
      user
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `user.create_profile` instead.http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

I forgot  that in my Profile class I had a validation for username

#### model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Use friendly_id
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

    belongs_to :users

    mount_uploader :image, ProfileImageUploader

  validates :username, presence: true, length: {maximum: 16} # <~~
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
  validates :gender, presence: true, inclusion: %w(male female)
  
end
```

My OmniAuth was not giving the username therefore it was rolling back the commit.